# sql select query remove rows by comparing dates

Tags: sql, database, date, duplicates, select-query

I need to write a sql select query on a table, but I have 1 special condition that I have problem with. My table structure is like below:

```
ID       Name         Serial      CreatedOn
1         A            1000         2014-10-10
2         A            1000         2014-10-12
3         A            1000         2014-12-12
4         B            1023         2014-10-01
```

My query should compare createdon dates, if there is 1 or more records that names and serials are the same and the createdon date is less than 1 month older than the other ones, they need to be removed.
For instance, in my example table, row with ID=2 should be removed from my select query because it has the same data as the first row and the date is less than 1 month older, but it should show the third row since the createdon date is more than 1month older.

How can I write this select query?

Thanks,

Comment: is it oracle or ms sql or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with UNION, where you can get data ahead of 1 month always and in the second select you can remove duplicates using `row_number`

The syntax is based on MS SQL, if it is other DMBS, then date functions need to be modified.

```
SELECT ID,Name, Serial, CreatedOn
FROM Table1
where DATEDIFF(M, CreatedOn,GETDATE())   >1
UNION
select ID,Name, Serial, CreatedOn from
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by createdon ) as seq
FROM Table1
where DATEDIFF(M, CreatedOn,GETDATE())  <=1
) T
where T.seq =1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but the fact is I don't want to compare the data with the data 1 month away from current date. Each item needs to be compared with its own records. Like item name A can have 1 record with createdon date 1 year ago and another one 2 month ago, so both of them should show up in the report and item B can have 1 record with createdon last week and another one 3 weeks ago, so the records from 2 weeks ago for item B should be removed.

Comment: @ErfanZarger, you have one record with date as dec 2014 ? also is this sql server then above query will work, i am changing it with out assuming future dates.

Comment: I just mentioned some sample data, my actual table has thousands of records, I still don't understand why are you comparing the cratedon date with current date, that is not right.

Comment: @ErfanZarger, i am comparing with current date to see if it older than 1 month old. if it older than 1 month, reterving all records, other wise getting only oldest in the current month

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
Select bb.ID, aa.*
From (
    Select  Name, Serial, Min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn
    From (Select Name, Serial, Left(CreatedOn, 4)+Substring(CreatedOn, 6, 2) as tPrd, CreatedOn From Table1 ) a
    Group By Name, Serial, tPrd
    ) aa
Left Join Table1 bb             --> to get column "ID"
    On bb.Name = aa.Name
    And bb.Serial = aa.Serial
    And bb.CreatedOn = aa.CreatedOn
```

If you don't need column "ID".

This is the query

```
Select  Name, Serial, Min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn
From (Select Name, Serial, Left(CreatedOn, 4)+Substring(CreatedOn, 6, 2) as tPrd, CreatedOn From Table1 ) a
Group By Name, Serial, tPrd
```

this query is use, if the data type of column "CreatedOn" is string.

If data type of column "CreatedOn" is date, you have to change

```
Left(CreatedOn, 4)+Substring(CreatedOn, 6, 2) as tPrd
```

change to

```
Convert(Varchar(6), CreatedOn, 112) as tPrd
```